# XLST stylesheet for datax2 NDW data

Tags: xslt

I have this xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP:Body>
    <d2LogicalModel modelBaseVersion="2" xmlns="http://datex2.eu/schema/2/2_0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <exchange>
            <supplierIdentification>
                <country>nl</country>
                <nationalIdentifier>NLNDW</nationalIdentifier>
            </supplierIdentification>
        </exchange>
            <supplierIdentification>
                <country>nl</country>
                <nationalIdentifier>NLNDW</nationalIdentifier>
            </supplierIdentification>
        <payloadPublication lang="nl" xmlns="http://datex2.eu/schema/2/2_0" xsi:type="MeasuredDataPublication">
            <publicationTime>2017-09-22T08:06:40.007Z</publicationTime>
            <publicationCreator>
                <country>nl</country>
                <nationalIdentifier>NLNDW</nationalIdentifier>
            </publicationCreator>
            <measurementSiteTableReference id="NDW01_MT" targetClass="MeasurementSiteTable" version="945"/>
            <headerInformation>
                <confidentiality>noRestriction</confidentiality>
                <informationStatus>real</informationStatus>
            </headerInformation>
            <siteMeasurements xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <measurementSiteReference id="PZH01_MST_0690_00" targetClass="MeasurementSiteRecord" version="1"/>
                <measurementTimeDefault>2017-09-22T08:05:00Z</measurementTimeDefault>
                <measuredValue index="1">
                    <measuredValue>
                        <basicData xsi:type="TrafficFlow">
                            <vehicleFlow>
                                <vehicleFlowRate>600</vehicleFlowRate>
                            </vehicleFlow>
                        </basicData>
                    </measuredValue>
                </measuredValue>
                <measuredValue index="2">
                    <measuredValue>
                        <basicData xsi:type="TrafficFlow">
                            <vehicleFlow>
                                <vehicleFlowRate>0</vehicleFlowRate>
                            </vehicleFlow>
                        </basicData>
                    </measuredValue>
                </measuredValue>
                <measuredValue index="3">
                    <measuredValue>
                        <basicData xsi:type="TrafficFlow">
                            <vehicleFlow>
                                <vehicleFlowRate>60</vehicleFlowRate>
                            </vehicleFlow>
                        </basicData>
                    </measuredValue>
                </measuredValue>
                <measuredValue index="4">
                    <measuredValue>
                        <basicData xsi:type="TrafficFlow">
                            <vehicleFlow>
                                <vehicleFlowRate>660</vehicleFlowRate>
                            </vehicleFlow>
                        </basicData>
                    </measuredValue>
                </measuredValue>
                <measuredValue index="5">
                    <measuredValue>
                        <basicData xsi:type="TrafficSpeed">
                            <averageVehicleSpeed numberOfInputValuesUsed="10" standardDeviation="6.2">
                                <speed>50</speed>
                            </averageVehicleSpeed>
                        </basicData>
                    </measuredValue>
                </measuredValue>
                <measuredValue index="6">
                    <measuredValue>
                        <basicData xsi:type="TrafficSpeed">
                            <averageVehicleSpeed numberOfInputValuesUsed="0">
                                <speed>-1</speed>
                            </averageVehicleSpeed>
                        </basicData>
                    </measuredValue>
                </measuredValue>
                <measuredValue index="7">
                    <measuredValue>
                        <basicData xsi:type="TrafficSpeed">
                            <averageVehicleSpeed numberOfInputValuesUsed="1">
                                <speed>44</speed>
                            </averageVehicleSpeed>
                        </basicData>
                    </measuredValue>
                </measuredValue>
                <measuredValue index="8">
                    <measuredValue>
                        <basicData xsi:type="TrafficSpeed">
                            <averageVehicleSpeed numberOfInputValuesUsed="11" standardDeviation="6.13">
                                <speed>49</speed>
                            </averageVehicleSpeed>
                        </basicData>
                    </measuredValue>
                </measuredValue>
                <measuredValue index="9">
                    <measuredValue>
                        <basicData xsi:type="TrafficFlow">
                            <vehicleFlow>
                                <vehicleFlowRate>240</vehicleFlowRate>
                            </vehicleFlow>
                        </basicData>
                    </measuredValue>
                </measuredValue>
                <measuredValue index="10">
                    <measuredValue>
                        <basicData xsi:type="TrafficFlow">
                            <vehicleFlow>
                                <vehicleFlowRate>60</vehicleFlowRate>
                            </vehicleFlow>
                        </basicData>
                    </measuredValue>
                </measuredValue>
                <measuredValue index="11">
                    <measuredValue>
                        <basicData xsi:type="TrafficFlow">
                            <vehicleFlow>
                                <vehicleFlowRate>0</vehicleFlowRate>
                            </vehicleFlow>
                        </basicData>
                    </measuredValue>
                </measuredValue>
                <measuredValue index="12">
                    <measuredValue>
                        <basicData xsi:type="TrafficFlow">
                            <vehicleFlow>
                                <vehicleFlowRate>300</vehicleFlowRate>
                            </vehicleFlow>
                        </basicData>
                    </measuredValue>
                </measuredValue>
                <measuredValue index="13">
                    <measuredValue>
                        <basicData xsi:type="TrafficSpeed">
                            <averageVehicleSpeed numberOfInputValuesUsed="4" standardDeviation="3.63">
                                <speed>56</speed>
                            </averageVehicleSpeed>
                        </basicData>
                    </measuredValue>
                </measuredValue>
                <measuredValue index="14">
                    <measuredValue>
                        <basicData xsi:type="TrafficSpeed">
                            <averageVehicleSpeed numberOfInputValuesUsed="1">
                                <speed>54</speed>
                            </averageVehicleSpeed>
                        </basicData>
                    </measuredValue>
                </measuredValue>
                <measuredValue index="15">
                    <measuredValue>
                        <basicData xsi:type="TrafficSpeed">
                            <averageVehicleSpeed numberOfInputValuesUsed="0">
                                <speed>-1</speed>
                            </averageVehicleSpeed>
                        </basicData>
                    </measuredValue>
                </measuredValue>
                <measuredValue index="16">
                    <measuredValue>
                        <basicData xsi:type="TrafficSpeed">
                            <averageVehicleSpeed numberOfInputValuesUsed="5" standardDeviation="3.37">
                                <speed>56</speed>
                            </averageVehicleSpeed>
                        </basicData>
                    </measuredValue>
                </measuredValue>
            </siteMeasurements>
            <siteMeasurements xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <measurementSiteReference id="PZH01_MST_0661_00" targetClass="MeasurementSiteRecord" version="1"/>
                <measurementTimeDefault>2017-09-22T08:05:00Z</measurementTimeDefault>
                <measuredValue index="1">
                    <measuredValue>
                        <basicData xsi:type="TrafficFlow">
                            <vehicleFlow>
                                <vehicleFlowRate>0</vehicleFlowRate>
                            </vehicleFlow>
                        </basicData>
                    </measuredValue>
                </measuredValue>
                <measuredValue index="2">
                    <measuredValue>
                        <basicData xsi:type="TrafficFlow">
                            <vehicleFlow>
                                <vehicleFlowRate>0</vehicleFlowRate>
                            </vehicleFlow>
                        </basicData>
                    </measuredValue>
                </measuredValue>
                <measuredValue index="3">
                    <measuredValue>
                        <basicData xsi:type="TrafficFlow">
                            <vehicleFlow>
                                <vehicleFlowRate>0</vehicleFlowRate>
                            </vehicleFlow>
                        </basicData>
                    </measuredValue>
                </measuredValue>
                <measuredValue index="4">
                    <measuredValue>
                        <basicData xsi:type="TrafficFlow">
                            <vehicleFlow>
                                <vehicleFlowRate>0</vehicleFlowRate>
                            </vehicleFlow>
                        </basicData>
                    </measuredValue>
                </measuredValue>
                <measuredValue index="5">
                    <measuredValue>
                        <basicData xsi:type="TrafficSpeed">
                            <averageVehicleSpeed numberOfInputValuesUsed="0">
                                <speed>-1</speed>
                            </averageVehicleSpeed>
                        </basicData>
                    </measuredValue>
                </measuredValue>
                <measuredValue index="6">
                    <measuredValue>
                        <basicData xsi:type="TrafficSpeed">
                            <averageVehicleSpeed numberOfInputValuesUsed="0">
                                <speed>-1</speed>
                            </averageVehicleSpeed>
                        </basicData>
                    </measuredValue>
                </measuredValue>
                <measuredValue index="7">
                    <measuredValue>
                        <basicData xsi:type="TrafficSpeed">
                            <averageVehicleSpeed numberOfInputValuesUsed="0">
                                <speed>-1</speed>
                            </averageVehicleSpeed>
                        </basicData>
                    </measuredValue>
                </measuredValue>
                <measuredValue index="8">
                    <measuredValue>
                        <basicData xsi:type="TrafficSpeed">
                            <averageVehicleSpeed numberOfInputValuesUsed="0">
                                <speed>-1</speed>
                            </averageVehicleSpeed>
                        </basicData>
                    </measuredValue>
                </measuredValue>
            </siteMeasurements>
        </payloadPublication>
    </d2LogicalModel>
  </SOAP:Body>
</SOAP:Envelope>
```

I have this stylesheet

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope"
                              xmlns:pub="http://datex2.eu/schema/2/2_0"
                              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="SOAP:Envelope">
    <xsl:text>publicationTime,country,nationalIdentifier,msmtSiteTableRef_targetClass,msmtSiteTableRef_version,msmtSiteTableRef_id,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>msmtSiteRef_targetClass,msmtSiteRef_version,msmtSiteRef_id,measurementTimeDefault,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>measuredValue_index,basicData_type,vehicleFlowRate,averageVehicleSpeed_numberOfInputValues,averageVehicleSpeed_value</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="SOAP:Body"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="SOAP:Body">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="d2LogicalModel"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="d2LogicalModel">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="pub:payloadPublication"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="pub:payloadPublication">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="pub:siteMeasurements"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="pub:siteMeasurements">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(descendant::pub:measurementSiteReference/@id,',',"/><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="pub:measuredValue"/>
  </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="pub:measuredValue">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(ancestor::pub:payloadPublication/pub:publicationTime,',',
                                 ancestor::pub:payloadPublication/pub:publicationCreator/pub:country,',',
                                 ancestor::pub:payloadPublication/pub:publicationCreator/pub:nationalIdentifier,',',
                                 ancestor::pub:payloadPublication/pub:measurementSiteTableReference/@targetClass,',',
                                 ancestor::pub:payloadPublication/pub:measurementSiteTableReference/@version,',',
                                 ancestor::pub:payloadPublication/pub:measurementSiteTableReference/@id,',',
                                 @index,',',
                                 pub:measuredValue/pub:basicData/@xsi:type,',',
                                 descendant::pub:vehicleFlowRate,',',
                                 descendant::pub:averageVehicleSpeed/@numberOfInputValuesUsed,',',
                                 descendant::pub:speed)"/><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>

   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[De output now to .csv is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtVD4.png)

I can't get the measurementSiteReference/@id in a separate column . The ID is important for linking the GPS coordinates.

I have looked at this question: [DATEXII XML file to DataFrame in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47331175/datexii-xml-file-to-dataframe-in-python). But this stylesheet is for a single measurementSiteReference/@id not for multiple measurementSiteReference/@id

[I would like it like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuEuP.png)

Can someone create a xslt stylesheet for this??

Answer (score 0):

Easier way is to perform your transformation in one matched template with taking all required values as below:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope"
                              xmlns:pub="http://datex2.eu/schema/2/2_0"
                              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>  
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>  
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <!--predefined separator for further use-->
      <xsl:variable name="sep" select="','"/>
      <!--set column names-->
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('publicationTime', $sep,
                               'msmtSiteTableRef_id', $sep,
                                           'country', $sep,
                                'nationalIdentifier', $sep,
                      'msmtSiteTableRef_targetClass', $sep,
                          'msmtSiteTableRef_version', $sep,
                                    'msmtSiteRef_id', $sep,
                            'measurementTimeDefault', $sep,
                               'measuredValue_index', $sep,
                                    'basicData_type', $sep,
                                   'vehicleFlowRate', $sep,
           'averageVehicleSpeed_numberOfInputValues', $sep,
                         'averageVehicleSpeed_value', '&#xa;')"/>    
      <!--predefined separator for further use-->          
      <xsl:for-each select="//pub:siteMeasurements">
          <!--get ids for each further record--> 
          <xsl:variable name="ref.id" select="pub:measurementSiteReference/@id"/>
          <xsl:for-each select="pub:measuredValue">
              <!--get all required values in variables for further result concat-->
              <xsl:variable name="pub.time" select="ancestor::pub:payloadPublication/pub:publicationTime"/>              
              <xsl:variable name="pub.cr.country" select="ancestor::pub:payloadPublication/pub:publicationCreator/pub:country"/>
              <xsl:variable name="pub.cr.natId" select="ancestor::pub:payloadPublication/pub:publicationCreator/pub:nationalIdentifier"/>
              <xsl:variable name="pub.tab.ref.class" select="ancestor::pub:payloadPublication/pub:measurementSiteTableReference/@targetClass"/>
              <xsl:variable name="pub.tab.ref.version" select="ancestor::pub:payloadPublication/pub:measurementSiteTableReference/@version"/>
              <xsl:variable name="pub.tab.ref.id" select="ancestor::pub:payloadPublication/pub:measurementSiteTableReference/@id"/>
              <xsl:variable name="index" select="@index"/>
              <xsl:variable name="pub.basd.type" select="pub:measuredValue/pub:basicData/@xsi:type"/>
              <xsl:variable name="flow.rate" select="descendant::pub:vehicleFlowRate"/>
              <xsl:variable name="in.val.used" select="descendant::pub:averageVehicleSpeed/@numberOfInputValuesUsed"/>              
              <xsl:variable name="speed" select="descendant::pub:speed"/>
              <!--getting result with concat function-->                   
              <xsl:value-of select="concat($pub.time, $sep, 
                                             $ref.id, $sep, 
                                     $pub.cr.country, $sep, 
                                       $pub.cr.natId, $sep, 
                                  $pub.tab.ref.class, $sep, 
                                $pub.tab.ref.version, $sep, 
                                     $pub.tab.ref.id, $sep, 
                                              $index, $sep, 
                                      $pub.basd.type, $sep, 
                                          $flow.rate, $sep, 
                                        $in.val.used, $sep, 
                                            $speed, '&#xa;')"/>                                                 
          </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And result (as expected in your link):

```
publicationTime,msmtSiteTableRef_id,country,nationalIdentifier,msmtSiteTableRef_targetClass,msmtSiteTableRef_version,msmtSiteRef_id,measurementTimeDefault,measuredValue_index,basicData_type,vehicleFlowRate,averageVehicleSpeed_numberOfInputValues,averageVehicleSpeed_value
2017-09-22T08:06:40.007Z,PZH01_MST_0690_00,nl,NLNDW,MeasurementSiteTable,945,NDW01_MT,1,TrafficFlow,600,,
2017-09-22T08:06:40.007Z,PZH01_MST_0690_00,nl,NLNDW,MeasurementSiteTable,945,NDW01_MT,2,TrafficFlow,0,,
2017-09-22T08:06:40.007Z,PZH01_MST_0690_00,nl,NLNDW,MeasurementSiteTable,945,NDW01_MT,3,TrafficFlow,60,,
2017-09-22T08:06:40.007Z,PZH01_MST_0690_00,nl,NLNDW,MeasurementSiteTable,945,NDW01_MT,4,TrafficFlow,660,,
2017-09-22T08:06:40.007Z,PZH01_MST_0690_00,nl,NLNDW,MeasurementSiteTable,945,NDW01_MT,5,TrafficSpeed,,10,50
2017-09-22T08:06:40.007Z,PZH01_MST_0690_00,nl,NLNDW,MeasurementSiteTable,945,NDW01_MT,6,TrafficSpeed,,0,-1
2017-09-22T08:06:40.007Z,PZH01_MST_0690_00,nl,NLNDW,MeasurementSiteTable,945,NDW01_MT,7,TrafficSpeed,,1,44
2017-09-22T08:06:40.007Z,PZH01_MST_0690_00,nl,NLNDW,MeasurementSiteTable,945,NDW01_MT,8,TrafficSpeed,,11,49
2017-09-22T08:06:40.007Z,PZH01_MST_0690_00,nl,NLNDW,MeasurementSiteTable,945,NDW01_MT,9,TrafficFlow,240,,
2017-09-22T08:06:40.007Z,PZH01_MST_0690_00,nl,NLNDW,MeasurementSiteTable,945,NDW01_MT,10,TrafficFlow,60,,
2017-09-22T08:06:40.007Z,PZH01_MST_0690_00,nl,NLNDW,MeasurementSiteTable,945,NDW01_MT,11,TrafficFlow,0,,
2017-09-22T08:06:40.007Z,PZH01_MST_0690_00,nl,NLNDW,MeasurementSiteTable,945,NDW01_MT,12,TrafficFlow,300,,
2017-09-22T08:06:40.007Z,PZH01_MST_0690_00,nl,NLNDW,MeasurementSiteTable,945,NDW01_MT,13,TrafficSpeed,,4,56
2017-09-22T08:06:40.007Z,PZH01_MST_0690_00,nl,NLNDW,MeasurementSiteTable,945,NDW01_MT,14,TrafficSpeed,,1,54
2017-09-22T08:06:40.007Z,PZH01_MST_0690_00,nl,NLNDW,MeasurementSiteTable,945,NDW01_MT,15,TrafficSpeed,,0,-1
2017-09-22T08:06:40.007Z,PZH01_MST_0690_00,nl,NLNDW,MeasurementSiteTable,945,NDW01_MT,16,TrafficSpeed,,5,56
2017-09-22T08:06:40.007Z,PZH01_MST_0661_00,nl,NLNDW,MeasurementSiteTable,945,NDW01_MT,1,TrafficFlow,0,,
2017-09-22T08:06:40.007Z,PZH01_MST_0661_00,nl,NLNDW,MeasurementSiteTable,945,NDW01_MT,2,TrafficFlow,0,,
2017-09-22T08:06:40.007Z,PZH01_MST_0661_00,nl,NLNDW,MeasurementSiteTable,945,NDW01_MT,3,TrafficFlow,0,,
2017-09-22T08:06:40.007Z,PZH01_MST_0661_00,nl,NLNDW,MeasurementSiteTable,945,NDW01_MT,4,TrafficFlow,0,,
2017-09-22T08:06:40.007Z,PZH01_MST_0661_00,nl,NLNDW,MeasurementSiteTable,945,NDW01_MT,5,TrafficSpeed,,0,-1
2017-09-22T08:06:40.007Z,PZH01_MST_0661_00,nl,NLNDW,MeasurementSiteTable,945,NDW01_MT,6,TrafficSpeed,,0,-1
2017-09-22T08:06:40.007Z,PZH01_MST_0661_00,nl,NLNDW,MeasurementSiteTable,945,NDW01_MT,7,TrafficSpeed,,0,-1
2017-09-22T08:06:40.007Z,PZH01_MST_0661_00,nl,NLNDW,MeasurementSiteTable,945,NDW01_MT,8,TrafficSpeed,,0,-1
```