# Create XSLT file for datex2 to Pandas Dataframe conversion

Tags: python, xml, pandas, xslt

I'm trying to follow the solution for DatexII to pandas Dataframe conversion given in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47357282/5449497

But i can't figure out how to set up the desired xslt file.

My xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<d2LogicalModel modelBaseVersion="2" xmlns="http://datex2.eu/schema/2/2_0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://datex2.eu/schema/2/2_0 http://bast.s3.amazonaws.com/schema/1412764802683/DATEXII_DaV-MDM-001_dyn.xsd" xsi:type="D2LogicalModel">
    <exchange>
        <supplierIdentification>
            <country>de</country>
            <nationalIdentifier>DE-MDM-Landesbetrieb Straßenbau NRW, Verkehrszentrale</nationalIdentifier>
        </supplierIdentification>
    </exchange>
    <payloadPublication lang="DE" xsi:type="ElaboratedDataPublication">
        <publicationTime>2018-02-17T23:59:42.364+01:00</publicationTime>
        <publicationCreator>
            <country>de</country>
            <nationalIdentifier>DE-MDM-Landesbetrieb Straßenbau NRW, Verkehrszentrale</nationalIdentifier>
        </publicationCreator>
        <periodDefault>60.0</periodDefault>
        <timeDefault>2018-02-17T23:59:42.364+01:00</timeDefault>
        <headerInformation>
            <confidentiality>noRestriction</confidentiality>
            <informationStatus>real</informationStatus>
        </headerInformation>
        <referenceSettings>
            <predefinedNonOrderedLocationGroupReference id="dav.nw.mq" targetClass="PredefinedNonOrderedLocationGroup" version="201610261425"/>
        </referenceSettings>
        <elaboratedData>
            <basicData xsi:type="TrafficFlow">
                <pertinentLocation xsi:type="LocationByReference">
                    <predefinedLocationReference id="mq.MQ_A1.0816_HFB_SW" targetClass="PredefinedLocation" version="201610261425"/>
                </pertinentLocation>
                <forVehiclesWithCharacteristicsOf>
                    <vehicleType>car</vehicleType>
                </forVehiclesWithCharacteristicsOf>
                <vehicleFlow>
                    <vehicleFlowRate>600</vehicleFlowRate>
                </vehicleFlow>
            </basicData>
        </elaboratedData>
        <elaboratedData>
            <basicData xsi:type="TrafficFlow">
                <pertinentLocation xsi:type="LocationByReference">
                    <predefinedLocationReference id="mq.MQ_A1.0816_HFB_SW" targetClass="PredefinedLocation" version="201610261425"/>
                </pertinentLocation>
                <forVehiclesWithCharacteristicsOf>
                    <vehicleType>lorry</vehicleType>
                </forVehiclesWithCharacteristicsOf>
                <vehicleFlow>
                    <vehicleFlowRate>0</vehicleFlowRate>
                </vehicleFlow>
            </basicData>
        </elaboratedData>
        <elaboratedData>
            <basicData xsi:type="TrafficSpeed">
                <pertinentLocation xsi:type="LocationByReference">
                    <predefinedLocationReference id="mq.MQ_A1.0816_HFB_SW" targetClass="PredefinedLocation" version="201610261425"/>
                </pertinentLocation>
                <forVehiclesWithCharacteristicsOf>
                    <vehicleType>car</vehicleType>
                </forVehiclesWithCharacteristicsOf>
                <averageVehicleSpeed>
                    <speed>108.0</speed>
                </averageVehicleSpeed>
            </basicData>
        </elaboratedData>
    </payloadPublication>
</d2LogicalModel>
```

My Python code for Jupyter Notebook looks like this:

```
from io import StringIO
import lxml.etree as et
import pandas as pd

# LOAD XML AND XSL FILES
doc = et.parse('/home/User/Desktop/DataTest/traffic.xml')
xsl = et.parse('/home/User/Desktop/DataTest/traffic.xsl')

# INITIALIZE AND RUN TRANSFORMATION
transform = et.XSLT(xsl)
# CONVERT RESULT TO STRING 
result = str(transform(doc))

# IMPORT INTO DATAFRAME
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(result))
```

So far I've got the following XSLT (traffic.xsl):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:pub="http://datex2.eu/schema/2/2_0"
                              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                              xsi:type="D2LogicalModel">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="d2LogicalModel">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="pub:payloadPublication"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="pub:payloadPublication">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="pub:elaboratedData"/>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="pub:elaboratedData">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(ancestor::pub:payloadPublication/pub:publicationTime,',',
                                 ancestor::pub:payloadPublication/
                                 pub:elaboratedData/pub:basicData/@xsi:type,',',
                                 descendant::pub:vehicleFlowRate,',',
                                 descendant::pub:averageVehicleSpeed/@numberOfInputValuesUsed,',',
                                 descendant::pub:speed)"/><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>    
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And I get the following output:

```
deDE-MDM-Landesbetrieb Straßenbau NRW   Verkehrszentrale2018-02-17T23:59:42.364+01:00   TrafficFlow 600 Unnamed: 4  Unnamed: 5

0   2018-02-17T23:59:42.364+01:00   TrafficFlow 0.0 NaN NaN NaN

1   2018-02-17T23:59:42.364+01:00   TrafficFlow 600.0   NaN NaN NaN
```

I have no idea how the column names get created and how to get the desired data as output:

```
publicationTime predefinedLocationReference vehicleType vehicleFlowRate speed

2018-02-17T23:59:42.364+01:00 mq.MQ_A1.0816_HFB_SW lorry 0 NaN
2018-02-17T23:59:42.364+01:00 mq.MQ_A1.0816_HFB_SW anyvehicle 600 NaN
2018-02-17T23:59:42.364+01:00 mq.MQ_A1.0816_HFB_SW car NaN 108.0
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `python` + `pandas` + `xslt` ... then I saw the linked answer!  =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost there! Simply place a comma separated list in parent template for the headers and for any specific element or attribute value use `ancestor::*` for levels above *elaboratedData* and `descendant::*` for levels below:

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:pub="http://datex2.eu/schema/2/2_0"
                              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                              xsi:type="D2LogicalModel">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="pub:d2LogicalModel">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="pub:payloadPublication"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="pub:payloadPublication">
    <!-- HEADERS -->        
    <xsl:text>publicationTime,predefinedLocationReference,vehicleType,vehicleFlowRate,speed</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>     <!-- LINE BREAK -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="pub:elaboratedData"/>
  </xsl:template>  

  <xsl:template match="pub:elaboratedData">
    <!-- ROWS --> 
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(ancestor::pub:payloadPublication/pub:publicationTime,',',
                                 descendant::pub:predefinedLocationReference/@id,',',
                                 descendant::pub:vehicleType,',',
                                 descendant::pub:vehicleFlowRate,',',
                                 descendant::pub:speed)"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>     <!-- LINE BREAK -->   
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[XSLT Demo](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bnnZWf)

**CSV Output**

```
publicationTime,predefinedLocationReference,vehicleType,vehicleFlowRate,speed
2018-02-17T23:59:42.364+01:00,mq.MQ_A1.0816_HFB_SW,car,600,
2018-02-17T23:59:42.364+01:00,mq.MQ_A1.0816_HFB_SW,lorry,0,
2018-02-17T23:59:42.364+01:00,mq.MQ_A1.0816_HFB_SW,car,,108.0
```